# Tengo una duda sobre mi análisis del programa

Tags: lógica

Se supone que tengo que resolver el código sin codificar solo analizándolo ya los resolví pero quiero sabes si estoy mal en mi análisis

```
 int fun(int *k) { 
 *k +=4; 
  return 3 * (*k) – 1; 
  } 

   fun se usa en un programa como sigue: 

   void main() { 
   int i = 10, j = 10, sum1, sum2; 
   sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i); 
   sum2 = fun(&j) + (j/2); 
  }
```

Se supone que acá debo de evaluar dependiendo el sentido en que se ejecute la operación de sum1 y sum2 de  ya sea si es derecha a izquierda o de izquierda a derecha

```
   si es de izquierda a derecha o sea :

   sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i); 
   sum2 = fun(&j) + (j/2);   

   según yo este es el resultado

   Sum 1 = 19 
   sum2 = 34

  y ahora si es de derecha a izquierda o sea:
    sum1 = fun(&i) + (i / 2); 
   sum2 =  (j/2) + fun(&j); 

  esta seria la respuesta

  Sum1=34 
  sum2=19
```

```
  int fun(int *i) {
  *i +=5;
  return 4;
  } 

  void main() {
  int x = 3;
  x= x + fun(&x) 
  }
```

En este seria igual que en el de arriba
de izquierda a derecha seria

```
x= x + fun(&x) ;
X=11
```

derecha a izquierda

```
   x=  fun(&x) + x;

   X=7
```

Comment: No sé que estás haciendo, pero estás equivocado. Con el primer ejemplo al evaluar, obtengo: `sum1 = (i / 2)/*5*/ + fun(&i)/*41*/; //5+41=46`. Y no veo como podría dar otro valor. Pongo en comentarios lo que daría cada elemento de la operación y al final lo que daría sum1 (`46`).

Comment: Si efectivamente daria eso pero es que según como nos explico la maestra es que  dependiendo de como la direccion que se ejecute el prgrama retornara el valor .

Comment: Por eso tenia duda por que si no ejecute la linea de  *k +=4;  y me voy al return me da lo que yo puse .

Comment: y debería ser como dices tu pero me daría el mismo los resultado en cualquier sentido

Comment: Creo que lo que está probando tu profesora es que entiendas la diferencia entre usar en una función un parámetro por referencia y un parámetro por valor. Léete esto https://julioecheverri.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/paso-de-variables-por-referencia-en-c/ . Te ayudará  a entender porqué el resultado es diferente si se ejecuta la función primero en la asignación de la variable.

Comment: Es que ni tan si quiera nos explico eso .

Comment: y si le entendí a lo que dices tu pero me duda es por que debería de retonar un valor si se ejecuta primero la funcion por eso es a lo que entendi yo

Comment: Ya te pongo una respuesta que te va a ayudar más. Porque aquí no puedo formatear código.

Comment: hooo ok, esta bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que es más fácil si te lo pongo como respuesta y así puedes ver qué es lo que está pasando... Teniendo esta función:

```
int fun(int *k) { 
 *k +=4; 
  return 3 * (*k) – 1; 
  }
```

Analicemos que hace cada linea:

```
int fun(int *k) {
```

Definimos una función llamada `fun` que devuelve un valor de tipo `int`, y recibe como parámetro el valor **por referencia** de un `int` al que referenciaremos como `k`.

```
*k +=4
```

Al contenido de la variable a la que hace referencia `k` súmele 4. Esto quiere decir que el valor de la variable a la que `k` hace referencia **cambia** luego de que se ejecuta la operación.

```
return 3 * (*k) – 1;
```

Vamos a devolver un entero que corresponda a 3 multiplicado por el valor que tenga la variable a la que `k` hace referencia y se le resta el valor de uno.

Teniendo esto en claro, vamos por escenarios.

- Primer escenario: `sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i);`

Ejecutamos la operación de izquierda a derecha, primero se hace `(i/2)`, lo cuál sería  hacer `10/2` que da igual a 5; luego hacemos `fun(&i)`lo cuál incrementaría el valor de `i` (la variable a la que se hace referencia) en 4 (ahora `i` vale 14) y además devuelve el valor de 41 (`3*i-1=3*14-1=41`). Al final entonces `sum1 = (i / 2) + fun(&i);`  es equivalente a `sum1 = 5 + 41;`  y por lo tanto la variable `sum1` tendría un valor final de 46.

- Segundo escenario: `sum1 = fun(&i)+(i / 2);`

Ejecutamos la operación de izquierda a derecha, hacemos `fun(&i)`lo cuál incrementaría el valor de `i` (la variable a la que se hace referencia) en 4 (ahora `i` vale 14) y además devuelve el valor de 41 (`3*i-1=3*14-1=41`). Luego hacemos `(i/2)` que sería hacer `14/2`, porque la función  `fun` **cambió el valor** de `i` y daría como resultado 7. Al final entonces `sum1 = fun(&i)+(i / 2);`  es equivalente a `sum1 = 41+7;`  y por lo tanto la variable `sum1` tendría un valor final de 48.

Comment: hooo ok, me quedo mas claro en lo segundo GRACIAS